# Finding differences between tarred folder and ordinary folder

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, tar

I want to find the differences between tar folder and an ordinary folder. So I used "tar d folder2.tar folder" command in UNIX command line, but i didn't get any output. I couldn't even get the bash command prompt. How do i use "tar -d" command to find the differences between a tarred folder and an ordinary folder having files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `tar df folder2.tar folder`. You have to add the `f` flag so it doesn't try to read the tar from stdin.

Comment: Thanks a lot yi_H. I could use it now. But I am getting an error saying "tar: folder: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors" now. So I have a question. Is tar df used to compare only two .tar folders? Or can I compare a .tar folder and an ordinary folder with text files in it?

Comment: your tar doesn't contain a folder named `folder`.. at least not on the root level.. maybe it's `sometpath/folder` or it just contains on the root level the files within `folder`.. check your archive.

Comment: Important: This does not report new files in the directory that are not present in the tar file.